# Labeling elements of a grid

Tags: graphics, image-processing, labeling

Let's create a simple $3 \times 3$ grid of images

```
img = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}];
P0 = Show[GraphicsGrid[{{img, img, img}, {img, img, img}, {img, img, img}}]]
```

[image]

My question: Is there a quick and elegant way of adding labels (1), (2), ... , (9) at the upper right part of each image? The labels should be located outside the upper right part of each panel, like the following

[image]

**EDIT**

Obviously, the above is just a simple case. In my real situation I have a $4 \times 4$ grid containing 16 different images with different names. So the solution must not work only for the same image, repeated many times.

**EDIT II**

If I try

```
im0 = Import["Lena.jpg"];
imn0 = Labeled[im0, {Style["(1)", FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 12, Bold]}, {{Top, Right}}];
plot0 = Show[GraphicsGrid[{{imn0, imn0, imn0, imn0}, {imn0, imn0, imn0, 
 imn0}, {imn0, imn0, imn0, imn0}, {imn0, imn0, imn0, imn0}}]]
```

then I get

[image]

Why the labels are not shown properly?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
GraphicsGrid[i = 0; 
 Map[Show[#, 
     Graphics[
      Inset[i++; Style[Text["(" <> ToString[i] <> ")"], 18, White], 
       Scaled[{.15, .9}]]]] &] /@ Table[img, {3}, {3}], 
 ImageSize -> 300]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

Or maybe this is your after?

```
GraphicsGrid[i = 0;Map[Labeled[#, i++; 
     Style[Text["(" <> ToString[i] <> ")"], 
      Black], {{Right, Top}}] &] /@ Table[img, {3}, {3}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

As your edit,maybe

```
GraphicsGrid[i = 0; Map[Labeled[#, i++; 
     Style[Text["(" <> ToString[i] <> ")"], Black], {{Top, Right}}, 
     ImageSize -> 100] &] /@ Table[img, {3}, {3}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Nice! But as I explained the labels should be outside the image and at the upper right (not left) side.

Comment: Not exactly! The labels in your second approach are located next to the images, while I want them just above the upper right corner.

Comment: Well,English kill me. :)

Comment: Please, see my edit.

Comment: Yes, the third approach is just what I need! A last issue: what if the grid contain nine different images instead of the same `img`?

Answer (score 1):

In the following, I create a new graphics with `PlotRange` 0 to 1.2. I then use `Inset` to insert the image into the new graphics and specify that it should occupy the plot range 0 to 1. This means that I have a padding on the upper and right-hand side of the image of 0.2 plot range. That gives me space to put the text in.

```
img = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}];

labeled[img_, label_] := Graphics[{
   Inset[img, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {1, 1}],
   Text[Style[label, FontSize -> 12], {1.1, 1.1}]
   }, PlotRange -> {{0, 1.2}, {0, 1.2}}]

imgs = MapThread[
    labeled, {ConstantArray[img, 9], StringTemplate["(``)"] /@ Range[9]}
    ];

GraphicsGrid@Partition[imgs, 3]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Is there a way to insert the labels exactly at the upper right corner of each panel? In your approach the labels should be moved a little bit left.

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z That question indicates to me that you have not taken the time to properly understand the answer.

Comment: Two more issues: (1). In my real situation I have nine different images, while your method works for only one image, repeated nine times, (2) I should be able to control the fonts of the labels.

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z The images have different sizes or what? Provide a better example then. Why do you say that you are not able to control the fonts and the position of the labels? It makes no sense.

Comment: Please see my edit. All images have the same size but different names.

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z Ok, then my solution is perfect for your situation. There is no problem in applying it to your images.